# How to get the traffic flow statistics of each switch/device using ONOS controller?

Tags: java, sdn, openflow, onos

I am new to building ONOS SDN controller apps. How do we get the traffic flow statistics for all switches/devices ? Any help with the guidelines/documentation would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find detailed information from [OpenFlow Switch Specification](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.3.5.pdf). (This is for version 1.3. If you want to study other versions such as 1.5 you can take a look [this](https://www.opennetworking.org/software-defined-standards/specifications/) page.)

You can find all about statistics but for flow statistics related parts are:

> 7.3.5.2 Individual Flow Statistics
>
> 7.3.5.3 Aggregate Flow Statistics